# Unable to re-write the file in powershell using Out-File

Tags: powershell, file-io, out

I am trying to write a powershell script to write the output of a command to a file. It runs perfectly fine for the first time. When i re-run the script it comes with an error

```
Out-File : The process cannot access the file '//Filepath' because it is 
being used by another process.
+         (Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $command )| Out-File 
$file -For ...
```

Code block :

```
$command = { 
$x = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5).ToShortTimeString() ;
$y = "{0:HH:mm}" -f [datetime] $x ;
cd $path ;
dumplog ctisvr /bt $y /m "CSTAUniversalFailureConfEvent"
}
#$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName 
(Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $command )| Out-File $file -Force
```

Comment: Sounds like you have have an open IO stream that you need to close. You may want to check with Process Monitor to see if that dumplog command is in fact what's still leaving your file open.

Comment: I have only 1 thing writing to the file which is " Out-File $file -Force". the Dumplog has only start and end time and hence will not get into a infinite loop. Does the Out-File any command to end that stream ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that this is not PoSH cause issue but the dumplog command you are using. There are programs with will not lock files and those that will. I've never used dumplog, I can only speculate here.

So, it would be best to check for the process state of the exe and file before doing anything with it afterwards.

Like simply looking for a dumplog process after the first serialization is done, the kill any dumplog process before trying again.

If this is on a file share you can use...

```
Get-SmbOpenFile
```

Or

```
openfiles
```

If it is local you can do something like...

```
What file is open by a given program
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dumplog.exe'" | Format-List -Property *

Get the owner of the process
$ProcessId = Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'dumplog.exe'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $ProcessId -MethodName GetOwner

What process has a file locked or filter the results based on the file name:
($ProcessId = Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | where commandline -match 'CSTAUniversalFailureConfEvent')

Kill the process
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $ProcessId -MethodName Terminate
```